# Quarkus - Opentelemetry ParentBased Sample not working

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry

I have an application where certain libraries make calls that I'd like to filter out from traces. To achieve this, I'm using the DropTargetsSampler class in Quarkus OpenTelemetry. However, I've encountered an issue with child calls not being filtered out as expected when I switch to a parent-based sampler.

```
@Produces
@DefaultBean
fun dropTargetsSampler(): Sampler {
    val dropTargets = listOf("/foo", "/bar")
    val rootSampler = DropTargetsSampler(Sampler.alwaysOn(), dropTargets)
    return Sampler.parentBasedBuilder(rootSampler)
        .setLocalParentSampled(Sampler.alwaysOn())
        .setLocalParentNotSampled(Sampler.alwaysOff())
        .setRemoteParentSampled(Sampler.alwaysOn())
        .setRemoteParentNotSampled(Sampler.alwaysOff())
        .build()
}
```

When debuging the code, when it reaches the class DropTargetsSampler, the sampler still appears to be using the AlwaysOnSampler and doesn't consider the parent-child relationship for filtering.

This is what I would expect the value of sample inside DropTargetsSampler to be:

ParentBased{root:AlwaysOnSampler,remoteParentSampled:AlwaysOnSampler,remoteParentNotSampled:AlwaysOffSampler,localParentSampled:AlwaysOnSampler,localParentNotSampled:AlwaysOffSampler}

Looks like this is the default behavior (when no custom sampler is added), but when I add a custom sampler, it just becomes AlwaysOn instead.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This Java CDI sampler:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public static class OtelCDISamplerProvider {

    @Produces
    @DefaultBean
    public Sampler dropTargetsSampler() {
        var dropTargets = List.of("/tracer");
        var rootSampler = new DropTargetsSampler(Sampler.alwaysOn(), dropTargets);
        return Sampler.parentBasedBuilder(rootSampler)
                .setLocalParentSampled(Sampler.alwaysOn())
                .setLocalParentNotSampled(Sampler.alwaysOff())
                .setRemoteParentSampled(Sampler.alwaysOn())
                .setRemoteParentNotSampled(Sampler.alwaysOff())
                .build();
    }
}
```

produced this sampler:
[image]

I was not able to reproduce your issue in Quarkus 3.5.0.
If you keep having the problem, a reproducer project would help.